# QTableView - Not Getting Selection Changed Signal

Tags: qt, qtableview

I am fairly new to QT, and am having trouble understanding how the `QTableView` selection changed signal is handled.  I have setup a window with an openGL widget and a `QTableView`.  I have a data model class that is correctly populating the tableview, so I added a public slot to that class:

```
class APartsTableModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
public:
    AVehicleModel *vehicle;
    explicit APartsTableModel(QObject *parent = 0);

    //MVC functions
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &paret) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const;
    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const;

public slots:
    void selectionChangedSlot(const QItemSelection &newSelection,
                              const QItemSelection &oldSelection);

};
```

When I am ready to show the window with the table view, I allocate/initialize it like this:

```
//create the display view
AStarModelView *displayWindow = new AStarModelView(this,
                                                   starModel->vehicle);

//create the datamodel for the table view
APartsTableModel *dataModel = new APartsTableModel(displayWindow);
dataModel->vehicle = starModel->vehicle;

//create selection model for table view
QItemSelectionModel *selModel = new QItemSelectionModel(dataModel);
displayWindow->materialsTable->setSelectionModel(selModel);

//setup model and signal
displayWindow->materialsTable->setModel(dataModel);

connect(selModel,
        SIGNAL(selectionChanged(const QItemSelection &, const QItemSelection &)),
        dataModel,
        SLOT(selectionChangedSlot(const QItemSelection &, const QItemSelection &)));

//show the view
displayWindow->show();
```

When I set a breakpoint in the implementation of the slot function, I never hit it.  I've also tried not allocating a new `QItemSelectionModel`, but that didn't work either.  I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to pull the answer out of the discussion:

> What's the first thing you should check in QT when signals/slots don't
>   seem to be working correctly?  That your class has the Q_OBJECT macro
>   in it.  Added this to the APartsTable class definition, and now I'm
>   hitting the breakpoint

.

Answer (score 4):

When you call setModel() on the view, your locally allocated QItemSelectionModel is getting replaced by one created by the view. You shouldn't have to create your own selection model anyway. Just change your connect to

```
connect(displayWindow->materialsTable->selectionModel(),
        SIGNAL(selectionChanged(const QItemSelection&, const QItemSelection&)),
        dataModel,
        SLOT(selectionChangedSlot(const QItemSelection&, const QItemSelection&)));
```

Comment: Sorry, just reread your question and I see "I've tried not allocating a new QItemSelectionModel, but that didn't work either." Maybe this isn't the correct answer, although it is true that your local selection model will be replaced when you call setModel. You should also make sure that the SelectionMode on the view isn't QAbstractItemView::NoSelection.

Comment: I've set SelecionMode to both SelectRow and SelectItem, but neither seem to help.  I've also moved the setModel() call above the setSelectionModel() call to avoid replacing the new selection model.  Still no luck.

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the currentChanged() signal instead of selectionChanged()?

Comment: What's the first thing you should check in QT when signals/slots don't seem to be working correctly?  That your class has the Q_OBJECT macro in it.  Added this to the APartsTable class definition, and now I'm hitting the breakpoint.  

When does Friday get here?

Answer (score 1):

What's the first thing you should check in QT when signals/slots don't seem to be working correctly?  That your class has the Q_OBJECT macro in it.  Added this to the APartsTable class definition, and now I'm hitting the breakpoint.

When does Friday get here?

Answer (score -1):

`virtual Qt::ItemFlags QAbstractItemModel::flags(const QModelIndex &index) const`
must return `Qt::ItemIsSelectable | otherFlags`